# Starting Spring Cloud Config Server on Docker - InvalidRemoteException: Invalid remote: origin

Tags: spring-boot, docker, centos, dockerfile, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to start a Spring Cloud Config Server on a Docker container and I am getting Invalid Remote exception. Reading the logs it seems that the Docker container doesn't have access to the Volume but I am not sure. I am using CentOs. any suggestion will be appreciatted.

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
MAINTAINER jimis.drpc@gmail.com
COPY files/config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/spring-cloud/lib/
ENV SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='{"spring": {"cloud": {"config": {"server": {"git": {"uri": "/var/lib/spring-cloud/config-repo", "clone-on-start": true}}}}}}'
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java"]
CMD ["-jar", "/opt/spring-cloud/lib/config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
VOLUME /var/lib/spring-cloud/config-repo
EXPOSE 8888
```

Spring Boot application.properties

```
server.port=8888
management.security.enabled=true
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframawork.boot.autoconfigure.SecurityAutoConfiguration
```

logs:

```
test]$ docker build --no-cache --file=Dockerfile --tag=config-server:latest --rm=true .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   30.3MB
Step 1/8 : FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
 ---> 88d1c219f815
Step 2/8 : MAINTAINER jimis.drpc@gmail.com
 ---> Running in a204b40b9f04
Removing intermediate container a204b40b9f04
 ---> 456dacbfaefa
Step 3/8 : COPY files/config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/spring-cloud/lib/
 ---> 55d1d05d4999
Step 4/8 : ENV SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='{"spring": {"cloud": {"config": {"server": {"git": {"uri": "/var/lib/spring-cloud/config-repo", "clone-on-start": true}}}}}}'
 ---> Running in 5036de819188
Removing intermediate container 5036de819188
 ---> dfecf1c03d37
Step 5/8 : ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java"]
 ---> Running in bfbbe5d1ec20
Removing intermediate container bfbbe5d1ec20
 ---> 9395dc9a8c81
Step 6/8 : CMD ["-jar", "/opt/spring-cloud/lib/config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
 ---> Running in 0f5bc5285e8b
Removing intermediate container 0f5bc5285e8b
 ---> fc8e287837e7
Step 7/8 : VOLUME /var/lib/spring-cloud/config-repo
 ---> Running in 9125b1dcd48e
Removing intermediate container 9125b1dcd48e
 ---> 780c5215f875
Step 8/8 : EXPOSE 8888
 ---> Running in 7e752e7e84be
Removing intermediate container 7e752e7e84be
 ---> 8a664539c179
Successfully built 8a664539c179
Successfully tagged config-server:latest
[jimis@bv-vpc-1097 test]$ docker volume create --name=spring-cloud-config-repo
spring-cloud-config-repo
[jimis@bv-vpc-1097 test]$ docker run --name=config-server --publish=8888:8888 --volume=spring-cloud-config-repo:/var/lib/spring-cloud/config-repo config-server:latest
2019-04-11 16:22:17.683  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9b802ec4] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.3.RELEASE)

2019-04-11 16:22:17.983  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.m.c.ConfigServerApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-04-11 16:22:19.548  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=11be5ef3-61b1-3539-a246-b6326ba4f12c
2019-04-11 16:22:19.631  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9b802ec4] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-04-11 16:22:20.199  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8888 (http)
2019-04-11 16:22:20.250  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-04-11 16:22:20.251  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16]
2019-04-11 16:22:20.269  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2019-04-11 16:22:20.561  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-04-11 16:22:20.561  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2551 ms
2019-04-11 16:22:21.652  WARN 1 --- [           main] .c.s.e.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository : Error occured cloning to base directory.

org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidRemoteException: Invalid remote: origin
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:251) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar!/:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:306) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar!/:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:200) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar!/:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.cloneToBasedir(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:589) [spring-cloud-config-server-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Were you able to solved this ?